# How to show authentication in the browser using Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have a application which is used by registered customers and unless register your self in the portal you may not able to login.

And the  application is built on spartacus as front end and its hosted in the Azure App service.

The use case is, whenever we do a production deployment, we want the internal business users to do the testing first and once they approve the application, we want this to be open to the public.

Problem is we don't have control over login means once the site is removed from the maintenance page ,anyone who has the credentials can able to  access.So it means while business users doing the testing ,the public also can access the site, even before the business completes the regression.

In order to overcome this, we thought of adding a browser authentication like the one given below and asked our infra team to do some thing like this, so that the credentials for this authentication will be given only to the internal users not to public and the internal user do the regression and then release it public.But our infra team said this is not possible in Azure app service.Is there anyway that we can achieve this ? Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: How are your users authenticated? Will all business users have the same email domain?

Comment: Looks like you are looking at staging slot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots. It will allow you to deploy the app and validate the changes on a different url. once you are happy with the change, you can roll out to the production slot. configuration can be different so you could enable AAD auth on the staging slot for security reason.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri the customers are authenticated from auth0. When they hit the website url they will land on the home page and then clicking the login button will take them to Auth0 for login and then taken to home page.This process is common for all internal users as well as external customers.That's why we need to control this via authentication

Comment: Hi @Thomas isnt this like testing the build in an lower environment and push that to production? Apologies not much aware about these concepts. Plz advise.

Comment: It is about testing your production code and just swap when you've done you re regression test (just on of the use case).The code will be deploy to your prod webapp then you can just test the deployed code in your production webapp before publishing it

Comment: I am sorry @Thomas wondering how the solution that you provided help us to achieve the authentication that we are looking for in the browser ,what I see is that, you are suggesting the build to be tested in the lower environment ,which we have UAT already and doing it ,but its just that once we deploy that in production we don't have a provision ATM  to restrict the actual customers from login when the business users are doing the regression and this is what we are really looking to sought here,Kindly advise ,really appreciate our valuable thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: All good, Sorry I was just trying to give some alternative way of solving your issue. Validating deployed changes in production is one of the main reasons to use slots: Your changes are deployed to production but visible on a different url. you can do you testing then once it is all good, you swap the slot and the code is in production.

Answer (score 0):

> But our infra team said this is not possible in Azure app service.Is there anyway that we can achieve this ?

Yes, using App Service it is not possible.

You can authenticate/authorize your app using Azure App Service without using any SDK's and coding which is provided by Azure.

#### Supported Authentication Providers in App Service

- Azure AD
- Microsoft Account
- Facebook
- Google
- Twitter

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service#connect-to-backend-services-as-app) to implement **authentication/authorization** in your app.

#### Using CLI command to set authentication in Existing App

```bash
az webapp auth update --resource-group <YOUR RESOURCE GROUP NAME> --name <YOUR APP NAME> --enabled true
```